# Branch Policies limited to a Repository in Azure Devops via Terraform

Tags: git, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We have couple of repositories (lets say TFA & TFB) in a Project in Azure Devops which are inheriting Branch policies from a different "Default" policy.

We are planning to overwrite and disable those branch policies via Terraform because we are not able to commit to its main branches automatically. We want the scope to be limited to those two repositories (TFA & TFB).

Not able to find what will be the correct resource to use in my TF Configuration.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't ask a question, you just made a series of statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it appears that you have enabled the branch policies for all repositories in your project to protect all the default branches, therefore you are unable to push the commits directly to the default branches (`main` branch).

[image]

Kindly note that the polices are set in Project Settings -> Repositories -> Policies and would take effect for each default branches of all the repositories in this project and we cannot set exemption for certain repos to bypass these policies.

[image]

However, we can exempt users/groups to `Bypass policies when pushing` to the default branches of certain repositories, so that the user(s)/groups of users are not restricted by the branch policies.

You may use this resource to update [branch level permissions](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/git_permissions). Here is a sample for your reference, that works from my side.

```
data  "azuredevops_project" "example" {
  name               = "ProjectA"
}
data  "azuredevops_git_repository" "example" {
  project_id = data.azuredevops_project.example.id
  name       = "TFA"
}
data "azuredevops_group" "example-group" {
  project_id = data.azuredevops_project.example.id
  name       = "Contributors"
}
resource "azuredevops_git_permissions" "example-permissions" {
  project_id    = data.azuredevops_project.example.id
  repository_id = data.azuredevops_git_repository.example.id
  branch_name   = "refs/heads/main"
  principal     = data.azuredevops_group.example-group.id
  permissions = {
    PolicyExempt = "Allow"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Alvin Zhao, Thanks for the help, I think this solution would work out in my case. Cheers !